# Как отфильтровать таски по конкретной дате? React js Moment js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from './List.js';
import Input from './input.js';
import Filters from './Filters';
import TaskManager from './TaskManager';
import MultiplyAct from './MultiplyAct.js';
import DatePick from './DatePicker.js';
import moment from 'moment';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      tasks : [],
      filter : 'all',
      selected : new Set(),
      isSelectedAll: false,
      date: new Date(),
  };
    this.taskManager = new TaskManager();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    return this.taskManager.init()
      .then( () => {
        this.setState({tasks : this.taskManager.getTasks()});
      })
    .catch( (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

//some code

isTaskInDate = (task) => {
    if (( this.state.date - task.createdAt) < 86400000  ) {
    return moment(task.createdAt).calendar();
    }
  }

  filtredByDate = () => {
    return this.state.tasks.filter(this.isTaskInDate)
  }

render() {
    console.log(this.state.date);

    const { tasks, filter, selected, date, isSelectedAll } = this.state;
    const filteredTasks = this.filterTasks();

    const isTaskEmpty = tasks.length < 1;
    const isSelectedEmpty = this.state.selected.size < 1;

    return (
      <div id = "appContainer">
        <h1>Список задач</h1>
        <Input
          addTask = {this.addTask}
        />

{this.filtredByDate()} //filter method 

        {
          !isTaskEmpty ?
            <MultiplyAct
              toggleSelect = {this.toggleSelect}
              multiplyDeleteTask = {this.multiplyDeleteTasks}
              isSelectedAll = {isSelectedAll}
              isSelectedEmpty = {isSelectedEmpty}
              isSelectedInFilter = {this.isSelectedInFilter()}
            />
            : null
        }
        <DatePick
          onChange = {this.onChange}
          date = {date}
          isTaskEmpty = {isTaskEmpty}
        />
        <List
          tasks = {filteredTasks}
          selected = {selected}
          deleteTask = {this.deleteTask}
          toggleTask = {this.toggleTask}
          selectTask = {this.selectTask}
          addNumberValue = {this.addNumberValue}
        />

        <Filters
          filter = {filter}
          setFilter = {this.setFilter}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Я,бы предложил, Вам, удалить лишний код и оставить только массив/объект тасок, который Вы хотите отфильтровать, а также свой вариант решения задачи... иначе Ваши шансы на получение ответа будут стремиться к 0

Comment: уже все сделал )

Comment: В таком случае, было бы очень неплохо если бы вы рассказали как это сделали и приложили код, с помощью которого решили данную проблему(в ответ на вопрос). Ведь могут появиться люди со схожей проблемой.